# Como puedo seleccionar elementos de la base de datos de 5 en 5 hasta el ultimo? vuejs php

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentado imprimir de a poco los resultados de la base de datos, para eso los voy seleccionando de 5 en 5, para no traer todos de una, el problema es que yo los agarro por el id, con la consulta BETWEEN, es decir SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 5, este seleccionara del 1 al 5, y en js guardo el ultimo id es decir 5, le sumo 1 y 5, quedando la siguente consulta SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE id BETWEEN 6 and 10, el problema es cuando en la BD tengo 16 id, seleccionara hasta el 15, pero al seleccionar el 16 da error ya que no hay mas, como pudiera solucionar eso?

aqui el codigo:

php:

```
public static function getfinishedproducts($begin, $end) {
    if($begin == "" && $end == "") {
       $begin = 1;
       $end = 5;   
    }else {
        $begin = $begin;
        $end = $end;
    }
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `finished_products` WHERE `id` BETWEEN :begin AND :end");
    $query->execute([":begin"=>$begin,":end"=>$end]);
    return $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
```

js:

```
 mounted() {
    this.showFinishedproducts();
},
methods: {
    showFinishedproducts: function() {
        axios.get("index.php?url=get_finished_products").then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.begin = parseInt(response.data[5-1].id) + this.BEGIN;
            this.end = parseInt(response.data[5-1].id) + this.END;
            console.log("Actualizado: " + this.begin + " " + this.end);
            //this.listFinishedproducts = response.data;
            //this.filterFinishedproducts = response.data;
        });
    },
    hola: function() {
        axios.post("index.php?url=get_finished_products",{'begin':this.begin,'end':this.end}).then((response) => {
            this.begin = parseInt(response.data[5-1].id) + this.BEGIN;
            this.end = parseInt(response.data[5-1].id) + this.END;
            console.log("Actualizado: " + this.begin + " " + this.end);
            console.log(response.data);
            //console.log(this.length);
            //this.listFinishedproducts = response.data;
            //this.filterFinishedproducts = response.data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Eso tiene pinta de ser una paginación ordenada por id, no crees? Usa mejor "limit" y "offset" en tus consultas. Revisa por SO, que hay varios ejemplos

Comment: exacto, como seria en tal caso?

Comment: Sería algo tipo SELECT * FROM `finished_products`ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5, 0. Luego vas añadiendo más offset (limit 5,5, 5,10...) En caso de pasarte de número de registros, la consulta simplemente devolverá 0 resultados. Revisa por SO, que hay muchos ejemplos de paginación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías utilizar la cláusula LIMIT, de este modo podrás limitar el número de registros que recogerás. También aplicar un ORDERBY, ya que los datos pueden volver desordenados. Usa la siguiente sentencia para recoger los datos:

```
SELECT * FROM finished_products WHERE id >= :begin ORDERBY id LIMIT :end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una manera fácil de resolver esto a travez de LIMIT en MySQL , lo primero que debes saber  es que el comando Limit el cual muchos lo usan solo con el primer parámetro el cual limita la cantidad de registros a traer ej:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY columna LIMIT 6;
```

Pero si lo usamos con 2 parámetros el primero sera el registro de inicio($start) y el segundo la cantidad de registros a devolver ($limit)

```
SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY columna LIMIT $start, $limit;
```

Seteamos el valor lmite definido por ti:

```
$limit=6;
```

Luego determinar la cantidad de registros en la tabla:

```
$count=""; 
if($result = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tabla")){
             $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
             $count = $row[0]; 
             };
```

Una vez que ya conoces el valor total de los registros debes saber cuantas planas vas a mostrar para eso solo debes calcular.

```
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) {
          $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
           $total_pages = 0;
}
```

Una vez que tenemos todos estos parámetros podremos hacer la consulta en la base de datos la cual nos traerá solo los registros requeridos.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY campo LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,  $query ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error());
```

El ultimo paso es crear un ajax que lea un campo input de tu pagina el cual será el indicador de planas este campo también lo puedes dejar como solo lectura y que mediante este valor haga la carga del script php, recuerda que deberás sumar 1 al valor que estas leyendo y además de aquí saldra la variable $start la cual iras multiplicando por 5 para ver la siguiente plana , primera plana (1x5), segunda plana (2x5)....etc, ademas debes poner 2 botones o links por medio de los cuales avanzar o retroceder entre las planas, la creación del ajax es medianamente sencilla, ese paso te lo dejo por que deberás adaptar tu código al llamado mediante ajax, te adjunto el link de JQgrid en el cual la muestra de registros es parte básica de su interfaz. espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html